# How does setting parent position to relative and child position to absolute affect div centering with translate?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I want to understand what does setting the position of the parent to relative and then setting the position of the child to absolute do, I have seen people use this technique many times?

When I tried to center a div using translate(-50%,=50%), I had to set the position of the parent as relative and the position of the child as absolute. I am wondering, what does that do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, an element with `position: absolute` will be positioned in relation to the viewport. To be positioned relative to a different element — which must be a parent/ancestor element — that ancestor element needs have a position set (such as `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`). The absolute element in question will be positioned in relation to the closest parent with `position` set.

The translate settings just tell the absolute element where to be positioned in relation to the parent. (Note that there's an error in your code. There should be no `=`.) Also note that there are other methods for centering these days, such as with Grid or Flexbox.

Comment: There's a little more to it than you have described. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example - for example an ancestor with position: absolute will also have an effect on positioning.

Comment: @AHaworth — Ah yes, I was focused on the particular question, but I've updated the comments to include any kind of parent/ancestor positioning.

Comment: Thanks for your clearn and concise explanation and yeah I actually wanted to add a negitive sign but rather added (=) by mistake, its just a typo